# PHP get var1 + var2 in url eg .php?=1something?=3

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, get

At the moment a chuck of my site is running off using GETs to direct to a profile or a page. But what if you go to someone's profile page (so that's one GET) and you then click a sub tab on their profile which uses another GET, can you do this:

```
http://example.com/something.php?xyz=4example=6
```

I have seen facebook do this however I'm not sure where to look.

An alternate to this would be Javascript however I would rather do it with PHP if possible.

Comment: You want to spare the request for each tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should be

```
example.com/something.php?xyz=4&example=6
```

Note the ampersand '&' between the get vars.

To access the vars in php use

```
$xyz     = $_GET['xyz'];
$example = $_GET['example'];
```

Comment: They are accessable in the $_GET array with their names. $_GET[example] equals 6 etc.

Comment: That is the answer. It should work with $_GET[your_param] of course.

Comment: @adeneo so something like $pageCatagory = $_GET['xyz']; $something = $_GET['example']; ?

Comment: yes, pretty much. It's a good idea to check them with 'isset' first.

Comment: you don't have to reassign the values to use them

Comment: @Dagon do you mean the variable?

Comment: Dagon means that you can use $_GET['example'] throughout the code as well. No need to define a new var.

Comment: default values: `$_GET += array('xyz' => NULL, 'example' => NULL);`

Comment: Would the link look like: viewmembers.php?=<? $userid ?>&cat=2

Comment: @IanGarratt it would have to look more like this `viewmembers.php?userid=<? echo $userid; ?>&cat=2`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure ur exact question but in general if you want to pass values to a page through url u should do e.g.
http://example.com/page1.php?var1=val1&var2=val2....

Please note that each new variable after the first one has "&" before it. This tells the server that a new variable is expected, and the first variable has "?" before it, which tells the server to expect variables.

In the php page you can get the values of all the passed variables like

```
<?php 
$_GET['var1']
$_GET['var2']
.
.
.
?>
```

and further user the values however you like. Note that you can not change a value in $_GET['var1']. If you want to change a value. First assign this value to a variable then further process. e.g

```
<?php
$var1 = $_GET['var1'];
$var1++;
?>
```